# Free webfonts visually similar to Lineto Circular

Tags: web-fonts, font-recommendation

Anybody know of any free webfonts visually similar to the new sans-serif Circular from Lineto that's being used at the new [Airbnb](http://airbnb.com) site?

http://lineto.com/The+Fonts/Font+Categories/Text+Fonts/Circular/Book/About+this+Font/

[image]

Comment: Circular *is* available as a webfont: http://lineto.com/Lineto.com/Lineto+Webfonts/

Comment: As it is, it's just not a good fit for the SE format. It's mostly opinion. And without knowing what you want to use it for, why you can't use the actual font, what similarities you are looking for, etc, it's hard for us to give any specific advice.

Comment: Mark, You probably already know this, but make sure to keep web font properties simple in design stage so they can be properly recreated with CSS.

Comment: I actually contacted Lineto (who licenses this font). AirBnB doesn't use Circular, per se, it uses "Circular Air" -- a customized version they had created for them. Also, these are licensed fonts, and technically illegal to just copy and use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ah, thanks for the edit. That helps to understand you're looking for a freely licensed typeface.

So, Circular itself is inspired by Futura, so likely you want web fonts that are inspired by Futura.

A [google search will return plenty of suggestions](https://www.google.com/search?q=google%20web%20font%20alternative%20to%20futura).

One result is [Joel Crawford's web site](http://joelcrawfordsmith.com/new/font/futura) where he lists the closest Google Font match to a whole range of typefaces. For Futura, [he recommends Nunito](http://joelcrawfordsmith.com/new/font/futura).

Answer (score 6):

while as not as refined as Circular, I found Google's Karla to be quite in style with the recent trend of geometric sans-serifs.

http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Karla

Answer (score 3):

Poppins is very close to Futura

https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Poppins

Comment: Hey Brian, thanks for your answer and welcome to GD.SE. Could you post a screenshot of Poppins in use, so we don't have to go off-site to see that your answer is fitting? Thanks! If you have any questions about GDSE, have a look at the [help] or feel free to join us in [chat] once your reputation allows you to (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

As of Jan 2020, there's an incredibly similar free alternative to Circular: **+Jakarta Sans**.

[image: +Jakarta Sans vs. Circular comparison]

It's got the same distinctive "t", as well as a generally similar overall feel. Honestly, apart from the "a", it's tough to identify one from the other – although side-by-side, Jakarta's round letterforms look more circular than Circular (ironically!).

What it’s got: 3 weights + italics

Get it at: [+Jakarta Text at Github.io](https://tokotype.github.io/plusjakarta-sans/)

I've compiled [3 other free alternatives to Circular here](https://learnui.design/blog/circular-similar-fonts.html).

Answer (score 0):

have a look at type ateliers Gordita font

https://typeatelier.com/font/gordita/

Comment: Hi user134620 and welcome to GDSE. OP is looking for a free web font so you may want to edit your answer

Answer (score 0):

Working with [Pepper](https://www.pepper-designs.com/), I have worked on several web fonts and I found three Google fonts that seems to be more closely identical to your preference.

https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Nunito+Sans
https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Raleway
https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat

Answer (score 0):

I like the lesser known Google Webfont [DM Sans](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/DM+Sans) best as an alternative for Circular.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Arimo was the best match for me.
https://www.google.com/fonts#QuickUsePlace:quickUse/Family:Arimo

Comment: Could you please include a screenshot of the typeface, so we can judge for ourselves without going off-site? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The closest free font I come across is "Inter" Google font. https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Inter